# How I can apply a vcl style to a TPopupmenu?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I'm using the vcl styles in a Delphi XE2 application, but when i popup a TPopupmenu this is show using the native windows look and feel, exist any way to apply the vcl style colors to the TPopUpMenu?

[image]

Comment: @RRUZ, it's your turn :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace the TPopupmenu  for a [TPopupActionBar](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ActnPopup.TPopupActionBar) or use a interposer class to cast the TPopupMenu to TPopupActionBar.

```
 TPopupMenu=class(Vcl.ActnPopup.TPopupActionBar);
```

Also you can read this [`Adding VCL Styles support to a TPopupMenu in 2 lines of code`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/adding-vcl-styles-support-to-a-tpopupmenu-in-2-lines-of-code/)

[image]